# Java split() method can not distinguish "." and "-" on Windows

Tags: java

For example:

```
"xxxxx-ex-xxxxx.ex-xxxx".split(".ex")
```

The results would be "xxxxx", "-xxxxx" and "-xxxx", that means the "-ex" has been identified as ".ex".

Of course, "\.ex" works well in this case. I just wondering why does it happened? Seems like it only occurred on Windows.

Comment: Please note, [`String#split(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) expects a regular expression.  Both `.` and `-` are used by the reg-exp engine to denote different requirements/features

Comment: "why does it happened" What do you mean? You must say what the expression returns and what you want it to return.

Comment: It happens on all platforms, because the argument to `String.split()` is a regular expression. The leading `.` in your expression means 'any character', which includes `-`.

Answer (score 3):

When invoking `"xxxxx-ex-xxxxx.ex-xxxx".split(".ex")` you're invoking [java.lang.String.split()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)). This method accepts ".ex" as a regex (Regular Expression).

We can use RegExr to learn about regex and see why the -ex part is also identified.
I inputted your string and regex into the website already: https://regexr.com/4rq3o

From that tool we can see that the dot `.` is special and means match any character, so by typing ".ex" it means find a pattern where any character followed by ex is present.

In order to treat ".ex" as a literal string, we need to escape the dot. As you discovered, `\.ex` does the trick because back-slash is an escape character.

Comment: Thanks a lot man! "Matches any character except linebreaks. Equivalent to [^\n\r]." explains everything!

Comment: @DanielDai No worries, if it completely answers your question, please mark it as the answer with the check mark button. (: